# What SIGHASH flags does CoinJoin use?

Tags: coinjoin, sighash-flags

What SIGHASH flags are used when constructing a CoinJoin transaction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CoinJoin uses `SIGHASH_ALL`.](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#coinjoin)

I initially found this confusing because I assumed the interface to CoinJoin a little less synchronized than it is. CoinJoin requires each participant to first specify a UTXO and a public key to pay out to.

*Someone* then constructs a partially complete transaction which makes use of those UTXOs and pays out to the public keys specified by the participants -- this transaction is "partially complete" because it doesn't yet have signatures which unencumber the UTXOs. Each participant then signs their input with `SIGHASH_ALL`, which prevents outputs from being manipulated after the fact.